# Why is C# Rounding This Way?

Tags: c#, floating-point, rounding

So, I've got this floating point number:

`(float)-123456.668915`

It's a number chosen at random because I'm doing some unit testing for a chunk of BCD code I'm writing. Whenever I go to compare the number above with a a string (`"-123456.668915"` to be clear), I'm getting an issue with how C# rounded the number. It rounds it to -123456.7. This has been checked in NUnit and with straight console output.

Why is it rounding like this? According to MSDN, the range of float is approximately -3.4 * 10^38 to +3.4 * 10^38 with 7 digits of precision. The above number, unless I'm completely missing something, is ***well*** within that range, and only has 6 digits after the decimal point.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> According to MSDN, the range of float is approximately -3.4 * 10^38 to +3.4 * 10^38 with 7 digits of precision. The above number, unless I'm completely missing something, is well within that range, and only has 6 digits after the decimal point.

"6 digits after the decimal point" isn't the same as "6 digits of precision". The number of digits of precision is the number of significant digits which can be reliably held. Your number has *12* significant digits, so it's not at all surprising that it can't be represented exactly by `float`.

Note that the number it's (supposedly) rounding to, -123456.7, *does* have 7 significant digits. In fact, that's not the value of your `float` either. I strongly suspect the *exact* value is -123456.671875, as that's the closest `float` to -123456.668915. However, when you convert the exact value to a *string* representation, the result is only 7 digits, partly because beyond that point the digits aren't really meaningful anyway.

You should probably read [my article about binary floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I was always under the impression that it stored 7 on either side, or at least 7 after the point. Lemme check that out.

Comment: @Nakaan: I've added a link to an article you may find useful. Given how large `float` values can be, it would be bizarre to *always* have 7 digits to the right of the decimal point... that would mean the largest numbers would have *46* significant digits.

Comment: Alright, I trimmed everything past the .6 and it passed the test and matched the expected output. Huh. Thanks a ton, I learned something new today!

Comment: Rarely (read: never) will you receive an answer from Jon Skeet and not learn something new :)

Comment: So I see from that ridiculous score. I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: +1... @SimonWhitehead - no, sometimes instead of learning something new you'll remember "I've already read Jon's article about exactly this last year" and forgot :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead He doesn't always answer but when he does, he gets lots of + votes :) EDIT: I'd be really excited if Jon Skeet actually answered one of mine haha.

Answer (score 0):

The float type has a precision of 24 significant bits (except for denormals), which is equivalent to 24 log<sub>10</sub> 2 ≈ 7.225 significant decimal digits.  The number `-123456.668915` has 12 significant digits, so it can't be represented accurately.

The actual binary value, rounded to 24 significant bits, is `-11110001001000000.1010110`.  This is equivalent to the fraction -7901227/64 = -123456.671875.  Rounding to 7 significant digits gives the `-123456.7` you see.